# Make a document library active on Office365 public Sharepoitn 2013 website

Tags: document-library

I have edited the default public site on Office365 Sharepoint 2013.

I have added the document library app on one of the pages in the site. I have shared this site but it is just a read only site (even though I have created a group with edit permissions) and doesn't show + add document in the web part of the document workspace.

How to enable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

See here. Read all the page. Basically you should not use the default document library but create and use a new one

Comment: This answer seems to be missing a link?

Comment: You answer is exceptionally vague, could you elaborate on this more?

Answer (score 1):

How to add a document library to the public website in Office 365
Log into outlook.office365.com as Admin of the public site. We use the Office 365 Business subscription, which has a hosted SharePoint 2013 Online server instance as a part of the subscription. 
Click the Admin link in the right most corner. This action navigates to the following page: https://portal.office.com/admin/default.aspx, which hosts the Admin Dashboard page.

Under Manage Your Organization locate the Website subsection and click the link titled "manage your public website". The Manage public website page opens. Click the link "Manage public website settings". This action opens the site settings page in a tab on the browser.

On the Site Settings page click the Site Contents link on the quick launch bar to the left of the Site Settings page.
The Site Contents page opens. Under the Lists, Libraries and other Apps section locate the add an app this opens the Site Contents -> Your Apps page. 
Select Document library under the Apps you can add section heading. This opens the Adding Document Library dialog box. Give the new document library a name. Click create. 
After the document library is created, you are returned to the Site Contents page. The new document library that was created is shown in the first row of the Lists, Libraries and other Apps section. Place the mouse cursor over the top right corner of the icon that represents the newly created document library. 
Click the ellipses to open a pop up that is named after the newly created document library, and contains three links. Settings, About and Remove. Click Settings, to open the Settings page of the document library. On the documentary library Settings page, under List information copy the web address of the document library. Click Edit Links on the quick launch bar, click the + sign to add a new link to the public website,this opens the  Add a link dialogue box. Give the link the name of the document library that you created and paste the link of the Web Address of the document library that you copied from the document library Settings page.
On the same Settings page click the link Permission for this document library . Under the Permissions tab, select Stop Inheriting Permissions from the ribbon above. This breaks the inherited security settings from the parent site in which the document Library resides. 
Select all the users displayed on the page, or those that you may specifically want to have access to the document Library. Click grant Permissions  under the Permissions tab. This opens the Share “library name” dialog box. In the invite people textbox, add the names of all those who should have access to the document library, or type, Everyone, if you want to share access will all. This will open a drop down list that contains two entries, Everyone, Everyone except external users. Take the second option to restrict access only to all company members, or Everyone, to share anonymously to the public.
Go back to the public website and you will see a link representing the name of your newly created document library, or whatever name that you give the link created previously.

Under General Settings click the List name, description and navigation link. This opens the General Settings  page of the document library. To the right of the Navigation section is a sub heading called Display this document library on the Quick Launch select the Yes radio button. You may optionally give the document library a description on this page as well, by type the description in the Description text box. Click Save